# How to export/import admin settings in M2?

Tags: magento2, importexport

Having set many settings in the back end, how does one export those so that they could be applied to another installation of Magento 2? (Or, for that matter, just review them all by eye in one go without having to poke through the UI for each one or few of them.)

Of particular interest are attributes and attribute sets, and all the extensive settings in **Stores > Configuration**

(I am already aware of Product import and export, **System > Export and Import**, but these don't cover the items I ask about here.)

This is for Magento 2.1.x CE.

Answer (score 2):

Magento all configuration data save in `core_config_data` table.

You can import all admin configration from one Magento-2 to another Magento-2 store.

Export `core_config_data` table from first magento store, which you have save all configuration data.

Import exported data to Magento another store, Which you want apply on the store.

Comment: That sounds appealing. Just to be clear: 1. All config data is in the one table, and no other tables need to be updated in concert? There's probably some cache clearing or reindexing to do?  2. Your last sentence -- I infer you're suggesting to edit the SQL dump file to delete unwanted settings, and include only the settings to be imported, right?

Comment: @gwideman By default all data is stored in that table. However if custom modules somehow uses a Backend Model and extends  *\Magento\Framework\App\Config\Value* to use the *afterSave()* method, then custom settings or data *could* be saved in another table.

Answer (score 1):

In Magento 2, on referring the devdocs, there is a way to export all the configuration settings into app/etc/config.php file than copy the settings from the app/etc/config.php maintaining the format / structure of the data than import the configuration from config.php file, for more details please refer the devdocs links as below:

Export - https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-config-mgmt-export.html

Import - https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-config-mgmt-import.html

This is the best Out of the Box way to export and import the configurations data.